# Who is this character associated with the Bat-family?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, character-identification

[image]

Who is the superhero in red and white with blonde hair in the following picture? When i do a reverse image search i just get articles referencing the Bat Family/Gotham Knights/Batman Inc, but nothing that identifies him.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### That would be Jean-Paul Valley aka [Azrael](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Azrael_(Jean-Paul_Valley)).

[image: Full body shot of Azrael in the rain looking off into the distance]

However, from a bit more of a look around (and I may be wrong here) I think the image you've found isn't from a comic but fandom art. The trail I followed led it back to being by an artist called Damion Scott. You can see it on [Comic Art Community here](http://comicartcommunity.com/gallery/details.php?image_id=12074).

Comment: The image in the question was pencilled by Damien Scott (and inked by John Floyd), but it's from _[Batman: No Man's Land Secret Files and Origins #1_ (1999)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_No_Man%27s_Land_Secret_Files_and_Origins_Vol_1_1). The image in the question is cropped, incidentally; the full image takes up two pages and has vertical strips running down the sides, listing all the characters' names along with some background information.

Comment: Wow, a Catholic vigilante named John Paul, who went by the name of the Angel of Death and whose last name references "the valley of the shadow of death"? Someone must have felt very proud of themself that day.